# Changing font of text in object pasted into PP using VBA in Excel (Table as Table in PP)

Tags: vba, object, copy, powerpoint

Problem: unable to change font of table pasted into power point.
I am copying a table (section of spreadsheet) into a powerpointslide (Layout is Title Only)
I need to be able to change the text in the table in the powerpoint. Therefore I used as Datatype:=ppPasteOLEObject. In Powerpoint I can change the font but I want to have it done in my programming.
Does anyone have an Idea? Thanks

```
Worksheets("Must Win").Activate
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
Page = Int(((LastRow - 1) / 5) + 0.5)
FIrstRow = 1
For i = 1 To Page
'Add a slide to the Presentation
  Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(Pages, 11) '11 = ppLayoutTitleOnly
 Pages = Pages + 1
'Copy Range from Excel

  LastRow = i * 5
  Set rng = Worksheets("Must Win").Range("A" & FIrstRow & ":M" & LastRow)
  FIrstRow = LastRow + 1
  rng.Copy

 'Paste to PowerPoint and position
  mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoFalse
  Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

    'Set position:
      myShape.Left = 40
      myShape.Top = 80
      myShape.Height = 400
      myShape.Width = 880
 'set HEader
    mySlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange = "Win Targets – Medical (Must Win) "
    mySlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 20 'Header

Next i
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce your results without re-creating a source speadsheet. In general, pasting as OLE results in an Excel object that is not reformattable in PowerPoint. You would have to set the font in Excel before pasting. Or better yet, apply the same theme to both Excel and PowerPoint, then they'll automatically match.

Answer (score 0):

To set the font size for a table, try the following instead...

```
  Dim myTable As Object
  Set myTable = myShape.Table

  Dim myRow As Long
  Dim myCol As Long
  With myTable
    For myRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
        For myCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
            .Cell(myRow, myCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 20
        Next myCol
    Next myRow
  End With
```

Comment: Dominic, I tried this and it worked right away. It does slow down the process a bit but saves re-editing the PP. My gratitude. Ray